# How can I, in Classic ASP/VBScript, get the value of a variable set with SET @local_variable?

Tags: sql-server, vbscript, asp-classic

I have a table that has a field of type [uniqueidentifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187942.aspx) which is going to be populated by a call to [`NEWID()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190348.aspx).

What I'd like to do is get back the GUID that was created right after I INSERT a record into the table.

If I run some SQL like the following from the SQL Management Studio it, very helpfully, prints out the value of my GUID

```
DECLARE @GUID uniqueidentifier;SET @GUID = NEWID();SELECT @GUID as guid;
```

**My question is, how can I get at the value of @GUID from Classic ASP using VBScript?**

I tried this

```
<%
conn.open Application("ConnectionString")

sql = "DECLARE @GUID uniqueidentifier;SET @GUID = NEWID();SELECT @GUID as guid;"
set res = conn.execute(sql) 

response.write res.fields.count
response.write res("guid")
%>
```

but it doesn't seem to work.  The `res` object doesn't have any fields so attempting to read the `guid` field errors out.

The error that I get is *Item cannot be found in the collection corresponding to the requested name or ordinal.* at the line where I try to read the value in `res("guid")`

Comment: could it be that `execute()` returns more than one recordset, one for each SQL statement? If so, you might need to call `res.NextRecordset`

Comment: when you say it doesn't work - do you get an error msg or ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you have simplified your query. The snippet shown works as is.

If however, you are running a stored proc or multi-statement query, conn.execute can return multiple recordsets, which you can step through using [`RecordSet.nextRecordSet`](http://www.w3schools.com/ado/met_rs_nextrecordset.asp) until you get to the last one.

Status messages can also interfere with recordsets, so make sure you use `SET NOCOUNT ON` in multi-statement batches.

Answer (score 1):

I use this all the time:

```
Dim rs , cmd
Set rs = server.createobject("ADODB.Recordset")
Set cmd = server.createobject("ADODB.Command")
cmd.ActiveConnection = Application("ConnectionString")

cmd.CommandText = "DECLARE @GUID uniqueidentifier;SET @GUID = NEWID();SELECT @GUID as guid;"

cmd.CommandType = adCmdText
rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient
rs.Open cmd, , adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly

response.write rs(0)
```

Comment: This is essentially what I'm doing but I get "Item cannot be found in the collection corresponding to the requested name or ordinal." on the `response.write rs(0)`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm misreading but what if you did something like this:

```
create proc dbo.myreturn 
as
declare @returnval nvarchar(255)

begin tran
DECLARE @GUID uniqueidentifier

SET @GUID = NEWID()
set @returnval=(select @GUID)

commit

select @returnval
```

Updated: Calling a stored proc from ASP: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/164485